# How can I make Angular's 'filter' filter filter deeply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have some things in an array:

```js
app.controller('ThingsController', function() {
    this.things = [
        {},
        {
            foo: 0,
        },
        {
            foo: -1,
            bar: null,  
        },
        {
            foo: 1,
            bar: { a: true, b: true },
        },
        {
            foo: 2,
            bar: { a: true, b: false },
        },
        {
            foo: 3,
            bar: { a: false, b: true },
        },
        {
            foo: 4,
            bar: { a: false, b: false },
        },
    ];
});
```

I want do display these things, and be able to filter the list based on some selection criteria. I may want to display only those things whose `foo == 2`, or whose `bar.a == true`, for instance. So, I wire it up to this HTML:

```html
<div ng-init="filterObj = {};">
    foo: <input type="number" ng-model="filterObj.foo" />
    a: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterObj.bar.a" />
    b: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterObj.bar.b" />
    <input type="reset" ng-click="filterObj = {};" />

    <ul ng-controller="ThingsController as ctrl">
        <li ng-repeat="thing in ctrl.things | filter: filterObj"><!-- content --></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This way, filtering on `foo` works just fine, but filtering on `bar` does not work as intended, as you can see for yourself in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emlun/xf6XT/). Specifically, setting either of `filterObj.bar.a` and `filterObj.bar.b` to either `true` or `false` makes the filter match any truthy `bar`. Filtering through `filter: filterObj : true` won't work either, since that would filter on *exact* deep equality (i.e. `filterObj = { bar: { a: true } }` wouldn't match any of the above things).

How can I make this filtering deep, so that `filterObj = { bar: { a: true } }` would match the things above whose `foo` is `1` or `2` but not the others? Will I need to write my own filter or [comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for this, or is there some trick I can use?

Comment: The `filterObj = { bar: { a: true } }` actually match things whose `foo` is `1` or `2` as you expected.

Comment: @runTarm: Yes, but it also matches the others whose `bar` is not `null` or undefined. I don't want that. :)

Comment: Ah I see, my angular version is 1.2.19 but in your jsfiddle is 1.2.1 that make the different. Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/byOGOMBjnnDsFWk1t7LV?p=preview for what I mean `actually match .. as you expected`. :)

Comment: You have to at least write your own comparator for your expectation since the default filter will convert anything to string before do a comparison. For example, `{ foo : 1 }` will match `{ foo: -1 }` because "-1" contains "1".

Comment: Weird, because I'm using version 1.3.0-beta.14 locally on my machine and getting the same results here as in the fiddle. :s Yeah, I've got a custom comparator running now that seems like it'll work for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using a custom [comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). It got even simpler when I realized there's [an underscore function](http://underscorejs.org/#matches) for this exact comparison.

```
app.controller('ThingsController', function() {
    this.things = [ /* ... */ ];

    this.filterComparator = function(actual, expected) {
        return _.matches(expected)(actual);
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in ctrl.things | filter: filterObj : ctrl.filterComparator"><!-- content --></li>
```